# How to solve this question based on diodes?

Tags: diodes

[image]
How to find the average using integration?

My attempt
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clearly show your attempt at solving this question. Is this homework?

Comment: Yes, I can. I'm not going to do your homework for you, though. Show an attempt first, then we might help.

Comment: @AJN Now can you verify ?

Comment: @Hearth Now can you verify ?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because the attempt is worth guidance as to how it can be dealt with much easier.

Comment: @StarLord If the question gets reopened, I'll write it up in an answer, but the general idea is that you don't care about the frequency - it'll vanish during integration. All you really care about is the average during first half-cycle (0-π) and then during the second half cycle (π-2π). The sum of those is the average over the entire cycle. Absolute frequency matters not since there are no frequency-dependent components in the circuit, and you assume that diodes have no capacitance.

Comment: @StarLord Also note that the circuit is basically two different circuits: Circuit 1 in the first half-cycle, circuit 2 in the 2nd half-cycle. Further observe that the integral is zero when the input voltage is below two diode threshold voltages. So integration is done from angle arcsin(1.2/5) to angle π-arcsin(1.2/5).

Comment: @StartLord Further, your solution may be correct. You'd want us to verify whether it is, right? Think of how you could do it yourself, also. As a hint: CircuitLab editor/simulator built into the question editor on this site lets you do the verification. Use the Ideal Diode symbol and set it to 0.6V forward voltage. The average is integral divided by time. A Laplace element set to 1/s is an integrator. CircuitLab supports Laplace elements. So you can plot the integral of the voltage over one cycle, and write down the final value, and divide by the period of integration - 10ms in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bridge rectifier which feeds load R5. The diodes have  substantial series resistors which reduce the current by being in series with the load, too.

The diodes block voltages 1.2 volts and less, so you can find the no current time or actually angle zone where Vi is closer to zero than 1.2 volts. During that period Vab=0.

The rest of the time (or actually the rest of the angle period 2Pi) the diodes subtract 1.2 volts. The diode series resistors + the load resistance and Vi reduced by 1.2 volts define the current i and the load gets its portion of the total voltage =(i * R5).

The imbalance of the diode series resistances for positive and negative half cycles of Vi cause 2 different pulses to R5. To calculate the average integrate in pieces:

- the zero period around Vi=0 (that part is zero)
- the nonzero i area of the positive half cycle
- the nonzero i area of the negative half cycle

Divide the sum of the partial integration results with the full cycle length to get the average.